# Changes done to mount path of reactjs app does not gets reflected in the web UI

Tags: reactjs, docker, npm, kubernetes, openshift

This is my dockerfile used to building an image for kubernetes/openshift deployment:

```
FROM node:8.11.4
RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json .
RUN npm install
COPY src src
COPY public public
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

The source code this  app is cloned from: https://github.com/nodeshift-starters/react-web-app

This is my deployment yaml:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: DeploymentConfig
metadata:
  name: 'react-app'
  labels:
    app: 'react-app'
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      initContainers:
        - name: init-react
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          image: "docker-registry.default.svc:5000/${NAMESPACE}/react-app"
          command: ["sh", "-c"]
          args: ["cp -n -r /app/* /tmp/app; sleep 1; ls -al"]
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /tmp/app
              name: react-storage-volume

      containers:
        - image: 'react-app:latest'
          name: 'react-app'
          securityContext:
            privileged: false
          ports:
            - containerPort: 3000
              name: http
              protocol: TCP
          resources:
            limits:
              memory: 500Mi
          volumeMounts:
            - name: react-storage-volume
              mountPath: /app                  

      volumes:
        - name: react-storage-volume
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: "${pv_react}-claim"

    metadata:
      labels:
        app: 'react-app'
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    app: 'react-app'
  triggers:
    - type: ConfigChange
    - type: ImageChange
      imageChangeParams:
        automatic: true
        containerNames:
          - 'react-app'
        from:
          kind: ImageStreamTag
          name: 'react-app:latest'
```

The `/app` is mounted to nfs mount path : `/mnt/k8sMount/react-data/`.

The observation is whenever a change is done to `src/App.js` in the NFS mount path, it is getting updated to the pod(i have exec to the pod and checked its content) but when the web UI is refreshed in the browser the changes are not shown up.
Another observation is if changes to `src/App.js` inside the pod then upon web UI refresh in browser the changes appear.

Since I would want changes done to `src/App.js` in the NFS mount path to reflect in the web UI, please suggest to me if anything is wrong the deployment or if any alternative to achieve this. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Kubernetes doesn't make sense as a live development environment.  I'd recommend deleting all of the volume parts and the init container from this Kubernetes setup, so that you're actually running the code from the Docker image.  If you need a local development environment, `node` is very easy to install and I'd recommend using that.